# Bottom bar added with interface builder doesn't display

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I wont to add a bottom toolbar to an iPad view. Although I add it with interface builder...

[image]

[image]

... I can't visualize it in my app. The only way to add a bar to the bottom is by dragging a toolbar from the library. Could you explain me why ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the property inspector, you will see that the dropdown you showed is in the "simulated metrics" section.  Changing those options doesn't actually change the layout, they are just there to help you visualize how the layout will look if they were to be there.

The reason for them is because some items (like the navigation bar on the top) are added automatically based on the circumstances, and adding them yourself in the interface builder would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the view is connected to the right view controller in the interface builder? There should be a tab that should allow you to specify a custom class. If you give that the name of your CustomView.m file then the two should connect and the bar should show. I hope that makes sense, but it's kind of late here and I am slightly tired.